# Nominatim search in openstreetmap is throwing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, openstreetmap, apache-httpclient-4.x, nominatim

I'm trying to call Nominatim Search API in my desktop java application, my code is:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=Köln&format=xml");
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But I'm getting following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
```

I have tried to explore Nominatim API, but I have not found any certificate. Can someone guide me, what I'm doing wrong or how can this be resolved.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @LukeWoodward i'm using java 6

Comment: You really should consider updating to a more recent version. In any case, the problem is that nominatim uses a Let's Encrypt certificate, and the default Java 6 truststore doesn't know to trust Let's Encrypt.